# Ayuda con Modelo Entidad-Relacion Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente duda, hice un modelo entidad-relación a partir de la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultandome el siguiente modelo con Power Designer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  r.rol_nombre, cli.cliente_nick, d.departamento_nombre
FROM    rol r, cliente cli, sesion s, ciudadela ciu, departamento d
WHERE   r.rol_id=cli.rol_id and
        cli.cliente_id = s.cliente_id and
        s.ciudadela_id = ciu.ciudadela_id and
        ciu.ciudadela_id = d.ciudadela_id and
        r.rol_nombre = 'servicios'
```

Obtengo como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo debería mostrar la facultad de "Ingeniería", pues según la tabla, "Katy" solo esta en esa facultad,

Por favor pueden darme recomendaciones o decirme que esta mal con mi modelo o mi consulta...

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda ...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que esta pasando es que realizas la consulta para todas las tablas, lo recomendable seria realizar inner join.

ejemplo:

```
SELECT  r.rol_nombre, cli.cliente_nick, d.departamento_nombre
FROM sesion s , 
inner join cliente cli on cli.cliente_id = s.cliente_id
inner join rol r on r.rol_id=cli.rol_id
inner join ciudadela ciu on s.ciudadela_id = ciu.ciudadela_id
inner join departamento d on ciu.ciudadela_id = d.ciudadela_id
WHERE r.rol_nombre = 'servicios'
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ejecute el codigo, pero sigue saliendo 2 facultades para el ususario, cuando solo deberia salir 1, la q esta en la tabla de la img.1 .... alguna idea de porque pasa eso?

Comment: puede ser que hay dos registros de sesion, he cambiado el orden de la consulta